# Run Java Programs residing on server

Tags: 12.04, java

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have uploaded a small java program (Hadoop Word Count) to a linux-server using FileZilla and now have to run that program onto server machine. I know how to connect to server using terminal i.e. ssh -l user-name ip-of-server But don't know how to run program that resides there. Please help me how to run that program from my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is to connect to the server this way:

```
ssh user@server -X
```

With the -X argument the session renders the graphical interface of the program in your client.

Answer (score 0):

You need a java compiler to compile your program before you run it to install the compiler, run the command `apt-get install javac`(assuming you are operating as root). You must  have your program saved with a .java extension. We will call it example.java .
When all of the above is in place, use the command `javac example.java` to compile and then `java example` to run. When you compile, bash not giving you any response is a sign that the compiling succeeded without error.
I have given this assuming you have used ssh to login to the server remotely